# Displaying Macvim Chinese character

Tags: macvim

My macvim cannot display chinese character properly and it showed me a `?` in square.

I try to put this `set fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,cp936,gb18030,big5,euc-jp,euc-kr,latin1` in my `.vimrc` file but the problem is not solved.

This is my `.vimrc` file.

```
set encoding=utf-8
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/neobundle.vim/
set fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,cp936,gb18030,big5,euc-jp,euc-kr,latin1

set guifont=Monaco:h15
colorscheme Tomorrow-Night-Eighties
runtime! custom_preconfig/*.vim
runtime! common_config/*.vim
runtime! custom_config/*.vim

" for git, add spell checking and automatic wrapping at 80 columns
autocmd Filetype gitcommit setlocal spell textwidth=80
map <F1> <Esc>

" auto complete special keyword such as _ and - for css and scss 48-57 means
" unicode character
autocmd FileType css,scss,coffee set iskeyword=@,48-57,_,-,?,!,192-255

" autosave on focus lost
:au FocusLost * silent! wa
```